# sending results from node.js to react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, axios

So on my `listPage`, I have 2 documents, where I want to be able to click the `edit` button, and it takes me to the `editPage`. It does do that right now. but what I have it doing, is making the request through an `axios.post`, so that it sends the `id` of the document to the backend, and then sends the results to the front end, where it'll only display the one document according to it's `id`. here's what I have:

listPage:

```
 const editById = (id) => {
console.log(id);
axios
  .post(`/getDocToEdit`, { id: id })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(id, " worked");
    window.location = "/admin/services/:site";
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle the errors here
    console.log(error);
  });
```

};

then it hits this backend route:

```
    app.post('/getDocToEdit', (req, res) => {

    var id = req.body.id;
    ServicesModel.findOne({_id: id}, function(err,result) { 
        console.log(result); 
        res.status(200).send(result)
    });
})
```

then I am just trying to display the document on screen in my `editPage`, but it doesn't load the result that I am sending through `res.status(200).send(result)`. I have just a table that is supposed to show the record. am I supposed to be doing a call from the front end again or something?

Answer (score 0):

you should save post result in your frontend:

```
const editById = (id) => {
console.log(id);
axios
  .post(`/getDocToEdit`, { id: id })
  .then((RESPONSE) => {
    console.log(RESPONSE); // do it and if you have the response, everything 
    is fine and you can use it as the returned data
    console.log(id, " worked");
    window.location = "/admin/services/:site";
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle the errors here
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: where do you have it? is it in the .then((RESPONSE ?

Comment: yes, when you use `res.status(200).send(result)` in the backend, you should grab `result` in your frontend for further processing. You can do it either with `await` or `.then(response)`. let me know if you have further question.

Comment: so I am doing the axios post to the backend on my list services page, and then I am trying to take the response from that, and use it in the edit services page. so doing this won't get me the results in the edit page

Comment: to solve this situation, you have two options: 1. use state managements such as redux or context provider, or 2. store the response in one variable and pass it to the desired component.

Comment: see these links https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#:~:text=React%20Redux%20is%20the%20official,the%20store%20to%20update%20state. and https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html but I suggest asking this in another question because it is totally different from your question here.